# Youtube retrieve/embed

Tags: php, database, youtube, embed

Is there a possible way where I can retrieve a list (with thumbnails) of my latest videos from youtube, store the embed code in a database using a cron job so I can show the video on a separate page instead of leading the users to youtube to view the videos? (all in php)

Comment: Yes you can do that in PHP.

Comment: references of how I can make this possible

Comment: For specific things like this are no tutorials you have to write them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to have a look at this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Google writes that:

> You can use the API to fetch search results and to retrieve, insert, update, and delete resources like videos or playlists.

I saw thath PHP API are still in beta version but you can try it out. You must register your application to obtain credential to use API. At developers.google there is a lot of documentation and some examples (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads)

Using API you don't need to retrieve code and store it into database, you can just show videos directly in your web application. I hope this is what you was looking for let me know if it helps!

Luca